# Encoding issues with .net core 2

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, .net-core

This code works as expected in `.net framework` but not in `.net core 2`

The file in.txt contains "Düsseldorf"

- in .net framework the output is "Düsseldorf"
- in .net core the output is "D�sseldorf"

(I've tried all the other Encodings out of desperation already... no one works)

```
string infile = @"C:\in.txt", outFile = @"C:\out.txt";

var inStr = new StreamReader(infile, Encoding.Default);
var outStr = new StreamWriter(outFile, false, Encoding.Default);

while (!inStr.EndOfStream)
{
    outStr.WriteLine(inStr.ReadLine());
}

outStr.Flush();
inStr.Dispose();
outStr.Dispose();
```

Any Ideas why it's not working?

Comment: please attach the file with the issue (truncated if possible). .NET Core usually defaults to UTF-8 but .NET Core 2.0 has codepage support enabled by default, which could have caused a similar issue in previous versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the official [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx) the default encoding is not fixed - it depends on the OS settings. If you know which encoding the file has, specify it!

EDIT:
Then try print the encoding details (like name) from the .net framework one that works. Then specify the same in .net core 2. Do not rely on the default one. This page [MSDN, List of encodings in the code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) contains a list of encodings that are supported.

UPDATE by gsharp:
I had to reference the NuGet Package `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`, register them and use it

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

 var enc1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

 var inStr = new StreamReader(infile, enc1252);
 var outStr = new StreamWriter(outFile, false, enc1252);
```

Comment: you pointed me to the right direction. Will edit your answer with my findings.

Comment: I had a similar problem and this solved it. CORE defaulted to UTF-8 but the code in my previous 4.6.2 solution was defaulting to Win-1252. Can also call the package this way: 

`var enc1252 = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1252);`